# C# - There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#

This may be basic OOP but I'm confused on how should this be implemented. I have 3 classes:

```
public class Flights
    {
        public string AirlineCode { get; set; }
        public string FlightNumber { get; set; }
        public string DepartureStation { get; set; }
        public string ArrivalStation { get; set; }
        public DateTime STD { get; set; }
        public DateTime STA { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return AirlineCode + " " + FlightNumber + " " + DepartureStation + " " + ArrivalStation + " " + STD + " " + STA;
        }

        public Flights(string airlinecode, string flightnumber, string departurestation, string arrivalstation, string sta, string std)
        {
            AirlineCode = airlinecode;
            FlightNumber = flightnumber;
            DepartureStation = departurestation;
            ArrivalStation = arrivalstation;
            string STA = sta.ToString();
            string STD = std.ToString();
        }

    }
```

I am trying to access those variables for this class:

```
public class FlightMaintenance
    {
        public void listOfFlightsAvailable(Flights flights)
        {
            List<Flights> listOfFlightsEntered = new List<Flights>();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Carrier Code: ");
            string AirlineCode = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Flight Number: ");
            string FlightNumber = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Departure Station: ");
            string DepartureStation = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Arrival Station: ");
            string ArrivalStation = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter STA: ");
            string STA = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter STD: ");
            string STD = Console.ReadLine();

            Flights newFlights = new Flights(AirlineCode, FlightNumber, DepartureStation, ArrivalStation, STA, STD);

            listOfFlightsEntered.Add(newFlights);

        }
    }
```

And when I'm trying to access the listOfFlightsAvailable() method in switch case in my main class, it is throwing an error:

```
 private static bool FlightMaintenanceMenu()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("[1] Add Flight");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] View All Flights");
            Console.WriteLine("[3] View Flights by Carrier Code");
            Console.WriteLine("[4] View Flights by Station");
            Console.WriteLine("[5] Exit");
            Console.Write("\r\nSelect an option: ");

            switch (Console.ReadLine())
            {
                case "1":
                    FlightMaintenance fm = null;
                    fm = new FlightMaintenance();
                    fm.listOfFlightsAvailable();
                    return true;
                case "2":
                    ReservationMenu();
                    return true;
                case "3":
                    return false;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
```

I'm fairly new to C# so it would be nice if someone can explain what needs to be fixed here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The method is expecting you to pass it an object of type `Flights`:

```
public void listOfFlightsAvailable(Flights flights)
```

But you're not passing it anything:

```
fm.listOfFlightsAvailable();
```

Usually the answer would be to pass the object that the method expects.  But in this case the method doesn't actually *use* this `Flights` object anywhere, so you may as well just remove it from the method definition:

```
public void listOfFlightsAvailable()
```